# Activity not being killed

Tags: android

At one point in my app, the user selects an image from a Gallery widget embedded into a selection activity. After selection, the next Activity loads.

The next activity uses more bitmaps. In an attempt to keep the heap size down, I am trying to destroy the selection activity after it is no longer needed. Using DDMS, I noticed that the activity was not being killed when I called `finish()`. I then proceeded to strip the activity down to the bare minimum and the activity still doesn't seem to finish. Below Shows what I'm left with

```
public class ImageSelectActivity extends Activity {  

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, 
                             WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);

    setContentView(R.layout.selectionpage);  
}

public void buttonClick(View v){
     Intent intent = new Intent(ImageSelectActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
     intent.putExtra("imageID", 0);
     startActivity(intent);
     finish();          
}
```

After finding the `ImageSelectActivity` still alive on DDMS. I looked at the path to GC roots and got the following:

```
Java.lang.Thread
 +- android.app.ContextImpl
  +- app.myapplication.ImageSelectActivity
```

Another thing, If I press back the application closes. I am completely lost. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's how Android works.  When you call "finish()" is essentially quits the Activity right there.  Android will not pull it from the list of running processes until it absolutely has to for performance reasons (why waste resources dumping resources that isn't needed yet?).  It will sit in memory until the memory is needed.  However, it's as good as dead.

The one exception to this (that I can think of right now) is if you have a thread running.  Threads will continuously run for forever or until they end, but they will continue to run after finish() is called.

On your last thing, if you're in the first `Activity` of your application, pressing the back button should close it (akin to calling `finish()`).

Comment: I don't believe the garbage collector will create the necessary space for a bitmap allocation. Hence why I'm getting OOM errors when only one activity is alive and it has no other significant memory requirements

Comment: I don't see why it shouldn't as Bitmaps are part of the full application.  When do you get the OOM exception?

Comment: In the onCreate() method in `MainActivity`

Comment: If you're really worried about it, you can call `recycle` on all of your bitmaps when your done using them.  If that doesn't work, then it may be you're actually allocating too much memory in your `MainActivity`.  It's difficult to know without actually seeing it.

Answer (score 1):

finish() should eventually lead to the activity being destroyed, when it is no longer referenced. The intent you're firing in your buttonClick-method holds on to the old activity, which, I guess, is why it's not destroyed right away. But don't worry about it. As long as you don't keep static references to View elements or stuff like that, the GC will get to it.

Comment: A quick look at a memory dump suggests that you are right. There is an Intent object pointing to both activities. I think I will still have a problem though. What if I run into an OOM error before the GC gets a chance to free it up

Comment: That shouldn't happen, as the android OS will find and kill other process' in times of low memory, which is why we aim to persist our state just before our activity leaves activity stack, or another activity is put on top of ours.

Good reading on the activity class and it's lifecycle: 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html

Comment: It shouldn't, but it does. It seems that when loading a bitmap, the garbage collector is not forced to create the space required and instead allows the program to crash.

Answer (score 0):

Anyway after the finish() you should user a return statement.